# Is Dynatable and ag-Grid plugin Scalable to large data?

Tags: reactjs

We have 20 million and more user data to process and sometimes a million users in a table.
Is the Dynatable and ag-Grid plugin Scalable to such a large data?

Dynatable: https://www.dynatable.com/?sorts%5Bcountry%5D=1#inputsearch
ad-Grid: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-cell-expressions/index.php

Answer (score 0):

ag-Grid plugin yes.

the grid doesn't care how large your data set is, it will only render into the DOM what is currently visible due to scrolling.

if you try to load lots of data into the browser, your browser will run out of memory before ag-Grid runs into rendering problems.

typically people will use ag-Grid's server side features such as pagination, virtual scrolling, or (will be released next week) viewport.

Comment: thanks for your answer... How about the Adazzle plugin (http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/basic)